# How to prove that addition of a new variable to the expression doesn't change its semantics?

Tags: isabelle

Here is very simple language:

```
type_synonym vname = "string"
type_synonym bool3 = "bool option"
type_synonym env = "vname ⇒ bool3"

datatype exp = Let vname bool exp | Var vname | And exp exp

primrec val :: "exp ⇒ env ⇒ bool3" where
  "val (Let var init body) e = val body (e(var ↦ init))"
| "val (Var var) e = e var"
| "val (And a b) e = (case (val a e, val b e) of
    (Some x, Some y) ⇒ Some (x ∧ y) | _ ⇒ None)"
```

I'm trying to prove that if an expression doesn't have any free variables, then I can declare any new variable at the begining of the expression. I've tried 3 approaches to prove it.

1) `defined` function checks whether the expression's value is well defined (= all used variables are declared):

```
primrec defined :: "exp ⇒ env ⇒ bool" where
  "defined (Let var init body) e = defined body (e(var ↦ init))"
| "defined (Var var) e = (var : dom e)"
| "defined (And a b) e = (defined a e ∧ defined b e)"

lemma var_intro: "defined exp env ⟹ defined exp (env(x ↦ init))"
  apply (induct exp)
    apply (simp_all split: if_splits)
```

2) The alternative approach is to collect all free variables from the expression. And if the expression doesn't contain any then we can add a new variable to the environment:

```
primrec freeVars :: "exp ⇒ vname set ⇒ vname set" where
  "freeVars (Let var init body) e = freeVars body (insert var e)"
| "freeVars (Var var) e = (if var ∈ e then {} else {var})"
| "freeVars (And a b) e = freeVars a e ∪ freeVars b e"

lemma var_intro2: "freeVars exp {} = {} ⟹ freeVars exp {x} = {}"
  apply (induct exp)
    apply (simp_all split: if_splits)
```

3) And the last approach is to eliminate all bounded variables from the environment:

```
primrec isFree :: "vname ⇒ exp ⇒ bool" where
  "isFree x (Let var init body) = (if var = x then False else isFree x body)"
| "isFree x (Var var) = (var = x)"
| "isFree x (And a b) = (isFree x a ∨ isFree x b)"

lemma var_elim: "¬ isFree x exp ⟹ val exp (env(x ↦ init)) = val exp (env)"
  apply (induct exp)
    apply (simp_all split: if_splits)
```

I can't prove any of the lemmas. Could you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proofs will probably require you to set `env` to `arbitrary` in the induction or the proofs will not work. With that, you will probably be able to prove the properties you stated, but I think it'll be a bit ugly because both your definitions and your lemma statements are unnecessarily specific, which can make proofs more painful.

In particular, your notion of ‘free variable w.r.t. an environment’ seems a bit unnecessarily complicated to me. I think it's easier to use the following:

```
primrec freeVars :: "exp ⇒ vname set" where
  "freeVars (Let var init body) = freeVars body - {var}"
| "freeVars (Var var) = {var}"
| "freeVars (And a b) = freeVars a ∪ freeVars b"
```

The statement ‘expression `exp` is well-defined w.r.t. an environment `env`’ is then simply `freeVars exp ⊆ dom env`.

Then it is obvious that any expression that is well-defined w.r.t. some environment is also well-defined with any bigger environment.

Answer (score 1):

1) You have to lift the communicative property of element insertion on sets into that of state updates on maps, on which your lemma is based.

```
lemma defined_dom: "defined exp env ⟹ dom env = dom env' ⟹ defined exp env'"
  by (induction exp arbitrary: env env'; auto)
lemma defined_comm: "defined exp (env(x↦a, y↦b)) ⟹ defined exp (env(y↦b, x↦a))"
  by (auto elim!: defined_dom)
lemma var_intro: "defined exp env ⟹ defined exp (env(x ↦ init))"
  by (induction exp arbitrary: env; simp add: defined_comm)
```

2) If your lemma is based on sets, you will also need the communicative lemma, which is already in the library:

```
lemma var_intro2': "freeVars exp s = {} ⟹ freeVars exp (insert x s) = {}"
 by (induction exp arbitrary: s x; force simp: insert_commute)
lemma var_intro2: "freeVars exp {} = {} ⟹ freeVars exp {x} = {}"
  using var_intro2' .
```

3) Similarly:

```
lemma var_elim: "¬ isFree x exp ⟹ val exp (env(x ↦ init)) = val exp (env)"
  by (induction exp arbitrary: env; simp add: fun_upd_twist split: if_splits)
```